# Making asynchronous API calls with jQuery and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm building an app that upon clicking the search button, needs to make two API calls.  The 2nd call requires data from the first request so I need some sort of asynchronous function to delay the 2nd call.  It's also important that I only make 2 api calls for every 1 click of the search button.  Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchButton").click(function(){
        var requestData = $("#searchBox").val();
        var resultElement = $('#resultDiv');
        var url = "https://api.trello.com/";
        var member_id_list = "";

        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: url + "search?title="+requestData
        }) 
        .done(function(data){
            $.each(data.items, function(key, value){
                if(value.member_id !== undefined){
                    member_id_list += value.member_id + ";";
                }
                resultElement.append($("<ul>").text(value.title)).append(value.body).addClass("question-body");
                $("ul").addClass("question-title");
            });

            $(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
                var member_id_list = member_id_list.slice(0, -1);
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: url + "/member/"+ member_id_list
                })
                .done(function(data){ });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

I haven't finished the part with what I would do with the 2nd API call (as I haven't been able to successfully make the 2nd call without submitting too many requests).

Comment: What are you asking? What is your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is not to use ajaxSuccess but to make the second ajax call in the done function of the first ajax call.

ajaxSuccess is called every time an ajax request completes successfully. No matter what ajax call: it is executed EVERY time.

What you want is to trigger the second call after the first is done (.done() function) or alternatively you can also use the success function of the fist ajax call (.success() function)

```
    $.ajax({
      method: "GET",
      url: url + "search?title="+requestData
    }) 
    .done(function(data){
        ...
    })
    .success(function(data){
        // second ajax call here!
        // or all code here if you only want to work with the data if successful
    })
```

EDIT:
Looking more closely at your code: I think all you need to do is take the out the line

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){
```

and its closing line. You should however think about the fact, that the done function is also executed if the server returns an error.

Comment: "that the done function is also executed if the server returns an error" if and only if the server incorrectly returns a non 40x/50x status code on error.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to make your requests as `synchronous`: parameter `async: false` for `$.ajax`.

Here is a suggested code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchButton").click(function(){
        var requestData = $("#searchBox").val();
        var resultElement = $('#resultDiv');
        var url = "https://api.trello.com/";
        var member_id_list = "";

        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            method: "GET",
            url: url + "search?title=" + requestData,
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data.items, function(key, value){
                    if(value.member_id !== undefined){
                        member_id_list += value.member_id + ";";
                    }
                    resultElement.append($("<ul>").text(value.title)).append(value.body).addClass("question-body");
                    $("ul").addClass("question-title");
                });
            }
        });

        var member_id_list = member_id_list.slice(0, -1);
        $.ajax({
            async: false,
            method: "GET",
            url: url + "/member/"+ member_id_list,
            success: function(data) {
                // Do whatever you need after the second request
            }
        });
    });
});
```